# How to wait for C program to finish executing in bash script Readme file

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, scripting, readme

I am new to bash scripting and I am trying to create a Readme file that will run a c program. The C program works fine and all it does is take user input, do calculations and display the result. How would I write a bash script which would wait for the user input and only remove the a.out after the result of my calculation has been printed on the console. I know I would have to use a while loop but how would I exit the while loop once my C program has finished and printed the result. I thought of including a sleep instruction but I wouldn't know how long the user could take to enter multiple inputs. Mind you my C program accepts multiple inputs; not just one. The current script I have doesn't allow me to take user input:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "C PROGRAM STARTED"
make -f Makefile all
pid = $!
wait $pid 
echo "END OF PROGRAM"
make -f Makefile clean
```

This is the result I get:

```
C PROGRAM STARTED
cc thread3520.c -lpthread -o ptf
END OF PROGRAM
rm ptf
```

Comment: When you run a command in a shell script, it waits for that command to complete automatically by default, `make -f Makefile all; make -f Makefile clean` should be all you need based on your description.

Comment: Make implicitly uses a file called Makefile - `make -f Makefile all` can be shorted to `make all`.

Comment: `$!` is only set when you run a command in the background with `&`. Also, you can't have spaces around `=` in a variable assignment.

Comment: `make` isn't normally used for running programs. As the name suggests, it's for compiling and installing programs. Run the program with a separate command after you use `make` to create it.

Comment: Before the while loop, try running it once. Perhaps `make all; ./a.out; make clean`.

Comment: @WalterA, one minor amendment to that -- looks like their executable should be named `ptf` rather than the default `a.out`

Comment: @WalterA You were right all I had to do was include ./a.out in the make all section. No while loop needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile creates the executable, it doesn't execute it.
Call the created executable before running `make clean`.